# Deadlock beween 2 update queries - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, deadlock

I am getting deadlocks between 2 update queries trying to update the same rows in the same table. One is holding a 'U' lock and the other is holding a 'IU' lock.

What are the best solutions here to try and avoid the deadlock?

I thought i could add an index that would avoid table scans but would this prevent the deadlock at all? Any advice would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Avoiding scans with query and index tuning is the best first step to mitigate the likelihood of deadlocks. As to whether or not it will prevent them depends on the particulars of your queries and workload.

Comment: Off-topic for SO - not directly a coding question. Better fit is [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). You need to understand how/why the deadlock is occurring.

Comment: Have a look at this article [SQL Server Deadlocks by Example](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/sql-server-deadlocks-by-example/). I believe the article is useful to understand better what deadlocks are and how to manage them.

Comment: Please post the queries and their execution plans. Also, do you have any transactions open at this time?